# Ok to mod exponents when solving modular expressions with integer exponents?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

We have $12^{12^{12}} \pmod{13}$. I tried solving it this way.

$12^{12^{12}} \equiv -1^{-1^{-1}} \pmod{13} = -1^{\frac{1}{-1}} = \frac{1}{-1} = -1$. But the correct answer is 1, why?

Comment: Instead, I will ask you: why should mod distribute over power towers? There is no reason why this should be the case. Consider as a simple example $2^3\,\mathrm{mod}\,3=8\,\mathrm{mod}\,3=2$, but $(2\,\mathrm{mod}\,3)^{3\,\mathrm{mod}\,3}=2^0=1$

Comment: $\bmod 13\!:\ 12\equiv -1\,$ so $\,12^2\equiv (-1)^2\equiv 1,\,$ so $\,12^n\equiv 12^{n\bmod 2}\,$ by [mod order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2033639/mod-of-numbers-with-large-exponents-modular-order-reduction). That is the *correct* way to exploit the modular period of powers - see the linked dupe (and its links)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $12\equiv -1 \bmod 13$, for any odd exponent $12^{2n+1} \equiv -1 \bmod 13$ and for any even exponent $12^{2n} \equiv 1 \bmod 13$. You just have to see that the exponent in your expression must be even and you are done.

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: WADR, OP is confused about a tetration issue, which the linked "dupe" does not address. My response merely pointed out that *in this instance* the tetration issue which is impeding OP's access to an answer can be finessed. If I can respond to a question in a few seconds, why should I spend twenty minutes looking for possible dupes, when the best putative dupes that others can come up with are not even on point?